# Write SQL row related content to file using Powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I am trying to write SQL Server stored procedure definitions to files using Powershell, I can execute the query and create the files in the loop, but the file content is all of the content (all data) not the definition for the current item in the loop that is being written

This is my Powershell at the moment:

```
$query = "select  o.name, cast(m.definition as varchar(max)) as content
from sys.objects as o
inner join sys.sql_modules as m on o.object_id = m.object_id
where o.type = 'p' and o.schema_id = 7"

$data = Invoke-Sqlcmd  -ConnectionString "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db; Integrated Security=True;" -Query $query
$folderloc="\\output\folder"
foreach ($row in $data.name)
{
    $fullname = $folderloc+$row+".sql"
    $content = $data.content
    new-item $fullname -ItemType file
    add-content $fullname -Value $content
}
```

Comment: Please provide examples of what you're actually getting and what you want.

Comment: Getting the correct file names.  One per stored proc, correctly named. However, I am getting all stored proc definitions (code) per file. So I need it to match up with the current proc being processed for the file name in the for loop. So the code associated with that particular procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I have it figured out.  I needed to change the loop to use the pipeline.  So replacing the ForEach loop in the above code to this worked great.

```
$data|ForEach-Object {
$fullname = join-path $folderloc ($_.name +'.sql')
set-content -path $fullname -Value $_.content
}
```

Also, I had to add the -MaxCharLength in the SQLcmd to ensure the output didn't cap at the default of 4000.